# Difference between jsp redirect url tag and response.sendRedirect() method

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have the following code to redirect to a new page from a jsp.

```
   //response.sendRedirect("someJspPage.jsp");  
   %>
      <c:redirect url="someJspPage.jsp" />
   <%
```

I see the first line is commented out. But I am not sure why.
I want to know what is the exact difference between `response.sendRedirect`  and  `<c:redirect url=`
Can anyone help me out to understand how the redirection works differently in both cases. I am writing a solution for a mixed content issue but I need to understand this difference first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them work alike. I believe you already know that the tag, `c:redirect` is a tag from JSTL (JSP Standard Tag Library) and is used to redirect the request to another resource. Like any JSP tag, the benefit of using it is to generate dynamic HTML without mixing Java code (e.g. `response.sendRedirect("someJspPage.jsp");`) with  HTML tags.

It also supports `c:param` e.g.

```
<c:redirect url="someJspPage.jsp" >
    <c:param name="someVar" value="1234"/>
</c:redirect>
```

In the case of `response.sendRedirect`, you will have to do it as:

```
response.sendRedirect("someJspPage.jsp?someVar=1234");
```

Comment: Not exactly true. The `<c:param>` properly uses `URLEncoder#encode()` under the covers. So that's a bit more work than what your `response.sendRedirect` snippet is trying to show.